# How does a CFT have both discrete energy spectrum and scale invariance?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

I'd think a CFT must have continuous energy spectrum, because if we use the dilatation operator $D$ to scale by an amount $\lambda$, the Hamiltonian $H=P^0$ scales as
$$e^{i\lambda D}P^0e^{-i\lambda D} = e^\lambda P^0,$$
and for any energy eigenstate $|E\rangle$ at energy E, there is some energy eigenstate $e^{i\Lambda D}|E\rangle = |e^\lambda E\rangle$ with energy $\lambda E$.

This same argument is often used to show that the mass spectrum (the spectrum of $P^\mu P_\mu$) must be zero or continuous.

So how can the energy spectrum be discrete?  Or when people talk about the discrete energy spectrum, do they actually mean the spectrum of the dilatation operator $D$? I'd also like to know about the case of CFTs in $d>2$.

Comment: Good question Emmy.

Comment: Can you give a specific reference on that CFT with discrete energy spectrum? I can think of reasons why that can happen (and all of them involve certain subverting of the conformal invariance) but would like to see what exactly are you talking about

Comment: I suppose the discrete spectrum is from the dilation generator.

Comment: The spectrum on $\mathrm{R}^{d-1}$ is indeed continuous. Instead, one most often studies the theory on $S^{d-1}$ (i.e. radial quantization on the cylinder) where the spectrum is discrete. Note that radial quantization is not limited to d=2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When one represents $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ unitarily, a natural basis of generators is made of the self-adjoint operators $H,D,C$  with commutation rules (on a suitable dense invariant domain)

$[H,D]=iH$

$[C,D]= -iC$

$[H,C]= 2i D$

It seems to me that you are referring to the first commutation rule that, exponentiated leads to your (correct) conclusion: the spectrum of $H$ is continuous. The same result applies to $C$ in view of the similar commutation relations.  The operator with discrete spectrum is another:

$$K_\mu =  \mu H + \mu^{-1} C $$

for every fixed $\mu >0$. This operator interpolates between $H$ ($\mu \to +\infty$) and $C$ ($\mu \to 0$) and plays a certain role in several applications of CFT.

For a discussion (actually applied to QFT in curved spacetime but the discussed mathematical results are general) see the old paper I co-authored  [Nuclear Physics B 647 (2002) 131–152](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321302009409?via%3Dihub) ([arXives](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0207072))